# Generated java file by Generators in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

How can I find the java file which is generated during compile time when Generator is being used, for example when we have uiBinder it seems that GWT.create calls some generators and generates a java file, how can I get access to this file?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The "-gen" parameter to the compiler nominates a directory where the generated code is put.  See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#What_are_the_options_that_can_be_passed_to_the_compiler

Comment: Thanks Ajan, could you please help me in more detail, I'm using Netbeans, I found gwt.properties file, then I should write something like this: gwt.compiler.gen= 'directory adders' ?